# Prisma 1.12.0 Could not connect to database. Socket is closed

Tags: reactjs, graphql, prisma

Hi I am following a tutorial and it uses prisma1.12.0 for the practice and heroku DB. I created the heroku db and installed the same prisma version. but when I run the command prisma init prisma it asks the DB related question like host, user, db name, password and ssl which I entered as per db credentials available on heroku and I entered ssl: true but at the end of questions where prisma is suppose to create 3 files it throws the following error message. I have lost quite a time on it but could not figure out what is wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

[image: Prisma error shown in terminal]

Comment: Hey, I mentioned this in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68313060/prisma-could-not-connect-to-database-socket-is-closed)  but didn't get a reply :/. Prisma 1 is  no longer actively developed and I would *strongly recommend* using Prisma 2 for any new application. Would you mind clarifying what tutorial you're following or your specific use case? In that case, I might be able to provide more actionable suggestions.

Comment: @TasinIshmam thanks for the response. I am following https://www.udemy.com/course/graphql-bootcamp/ from udemy. and my apologies for not replying on my previous post I was just waiting for someone to answer the solution at that time but i guess with prisma 1 that's not the case now :(

Comment: I understand :(. If you are willing to consider shifting to a course that uses Prisma Version 2, there's a few I can reccomend. We help maintain [howtographql.com](https://www.howtographql.com/) which contains a number of GraphQL articles across multiple technology stacks. Another possible alternative that teaches GraphQL with Prisma 2 is this [udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/end-to-end-react-with-prisma-2/) by Stephen Jensen.

Comment: thanks dear. that's helpful :)